# How to obtain SliceDistribution or StationaryDistribution for an ItoProcess when it is known to exist?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

According to this [reference page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StationaryDistribution.html)

> StationaryDistribution[*proc*] 
>   represents the stationary distribution of the process *proc*, when it exists.

When I define the OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess by the equivalent ItoProcess,  SliceDistribution and StationaryDistribution are not found analytically any more. See for example the following:

```
In[25]:= SliceDistribution[OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1, 1], t]

Out[25]= NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]]

In[27]:= SliceDistribution[
 ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
     t] == -x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
  x[t], {x, 1}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]], t]

Out[27]= ItoProcess[{{-x[t]}, {{1}}, x[t]}, {{x}, {1}}, {t, 0}][t]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the result is not displayed the way one would expect, the distribution is there :

```
PDF[SliceDistribution[
     ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
                 \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1}, t, 
                w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]], t], z]
```

$$\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{e^t \left(z-e^{-t}\right) \left(e^t z-1\right)}{e^{2 t}-1}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }
   \sqrt{e^{-2 t} \left(e^{2 t}-1\right)}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. To do with this issue, I suppose, `SliceDistribution[proc,Infinity]` does not work, neither does `StationaryDistribution[proc]`. But is there really not a way to use StationaryDistribution only? I'm thinking that may be there are cases when SliceDistribution does not exists, but StationaryDistribution does.

Comment: I found `Limit[PDF[SliceDistribution[proc, t], x], t -> Infinity]` to work, but I still have the question about StationaryDistribution.